# How to target a specific, currently active, element out of a group selection based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, this

I am trying to learn jQuery, and all of the stuff I read makes perfect sense, but then I try to do something simple and it fails.  Okay, so I have a basic image gallery, four rows, four columns, and I want to be able to swap out CSS classes when they move their cursor over the image.  Below is the relevant HTML that I am trying to target (I can put the whole file document up if necessary, it's just very long): Specifically, I want to select all images with the class `galImg` and attach a hover event handler, and from that handler, I want to swap out CSS classes.  Here is the jQuery I am using for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".galImg").hover(function(){
    $(this, 'img').removeClass(".img-thumbnail");
    $(this,'img').removeClass(".galImg").addClass(".pictureFocus");
         });
});
```

I know that I could call the event handler by sticking a bunch of onClick="functionName()" from every single image entry in the HTML document, but that seems redundant, and so I am modeling what I saw on another post very similar to this one in regards to that.  Where the trouble is, so far as I can see it (and I probably can't see it),  is that once I have the selection , I am having a hard time understanding how to specify the specific element that the mouse is hovering over.   If $(".galImg").hover is the selection, (which I am thinking of as 'all images with class .galImg that are placed in a hover state'), then in the function that is attached to it, how would I refer to the specific img that the user has their mouse over?   I really appreciate any time anyone takes to help me out.  It's my first day sincerely trying to do anything with the stuff I've been reading in JavaScript, and I feel very frustrated.  Thanks again for your time.

```
<div class="row coniferGal">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues in your code. The main one is that the second argument in a jQuery object is the context. This is effectively the same as `find()`. As such you're looking for an `img` within the `img` contained in `this` - which is why it does not work. Remove that second argument.

Secondly, don't remove the `.galImg` class from the elements. You selected the `img` by that. If you're expecting it to have an effect on the elements you select then you need a delegated event handler, but I won't go in to that here as there is no point removing the `.galImg` class in the first instance.

Thirdly, the `addClass()`, `removeClass()`, `toggleClass()` etc. methods do not require the `.` prefix on classes. You simply provide them as strings, delimited with spaces if necessary.

Lastly you can combine the separate `addClass()` and `removeClass()` calls by using `toggleClass()` alone.

For future reference you should note that jQuery has [excellent documentation](https://api.jquery.com). I'd suggest browsing it to familiarise yourself with the methods available - most of them are self-explanatory.

With all that said try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".galImg").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("img-thumbnail pictureFocus");
  });
});
```

```css
.galImg { 
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
}

.pictureFocus {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row coniferGal">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
  </div>
</div>
```

***However*** it's worth noting that JS/jQuery is not required for the example you've shown. The better practice in this instance would be to use CSS alone to update the hover state of the elements. This is because CSS has much better performance than JS, and also because JS shouldn't solely be used to update the UI, where possible.

Here's the same demo as above but built using CSS alone:

```css
.galImg { 
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
}

.galImg:hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row coniferGal">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="images/images/Gallery_03.jpg" alt="Chinese Maple" class="galImg img-thumbnail">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It works now, as per your solution.  I understand that the css can accomplish the same thing, and have been practicing some of that too.  But I would like to learn how to use javascript based frameworks (got a lot of work ahead of me), and the only way I can learn this stuff is to create little low level goals and follow through with them.  Thanks again for the help and the resource-pointing

Comment: No problem, glad to help.